# Firebase Orderby is not formatted correctly

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using Firebase as db and fetching the values based on ids. Created a field `order`, the lesser number it will show the value on first.
Have around 16 items. All working fine, but the issue is the order is not working properly, the data is showing as below example.

**Example**

1,11,12,13,14,15,16,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

**Result should be**

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16

**Function**

```
function fetchSlides() {
  var docRef = db.collection("Slides");
  docRef
    .orderBy("order")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      var totalRecords = querySnapshot.size; // Total amount of received records
      pg.tslide = totalRecords + 1; // Account for slide-1

      // Adjust zIndex of slide-1
      $("#slide-1").css("z-index", totalRecords + 1);

      // Parse and append received slides
      var count = 0;
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        var slide = getSlide(doc.data(), count, totalRecords);
        $(".slideshow").append(slide);
        ++count;
      });

      // Re-adjust page size
      pg.onResize();
      // Update scroll position
      pg.onScroll();
    });
}
```

The above function is fetching and display the data. 
do I have to change in `.orderBy("order")` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your "order" field is a string type rather than a number.  What you're showing is the (lexicographic) sort order for strings.  You can't change this behavior, since this is the way strings naturally sort, and you can't make Firestore think the type to be something other than what it really is in the database.

If these values should be numbers instead, you're going to have to update all the documents to use actual number types instead of strings.  The Firestore console will tell you the actual data type of a field if you hover the mouse over it.  Strings will appear in quotes, while numbers will not.

Comment: thanks for saving my day, I though I put the number and that make me confusion.